# Pre-commit mypy dep resolution not equivalent to running mypy natively

Tags: mypy, monorepo, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Crossposting this to SO since the issue was closed on the repo by the maintainer on Github https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/2951 without resolution and I'm unable to find out what the origin of the issue is/how to fix it.  It's possible it's something very simple that I'm missing, maybe even a one line change. Would really appreciate any assistance here and narrowing down what is happening.

**tl;dr** When I run `pre-commit run mypy --all-files` from the root directory of a monorepo ( https://github.com/Faolain/mypy-monorepo) I get the following errors:

```
mypy.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: mypy
- duration: 1.68s
- exit code: 1

packages/backend/src/app/domain/analytics/queries.py:6: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "aiosql"  [import]
packages/backend/src/app/lib/worker/commands.py:11: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "uvloop"  [import]
packages/backend/src/app/contrib/aiosql/service.py:12: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "aiosql.queries"  [import]
packages/backend/src/app/contrib/aiosql/service.py:12: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
packages/backend/src/app/domain/analytics/dependencies.py:7: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "aiosql"  [import]
packages/backend/tests/unit/lib/test_log.py:24: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "re2"  [import]
Found 5 errors in 5 files (checked 121 source files)
```

**However** when I run the following native command from an active venv (via poetry shell) from the very same root directory via CLI
`mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml packages/backend/src` of `mypy-monorepo` I get no type errors.

Additionally if I have that same command run on `entry:` aka `entry: mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml` (see: commented out line on .pre-commit-config.yaml below) within `pre-commit` I get the same behavior (no type errors). The problem is I can't run that `entry:...` on github actions (since entry does not run bash natively...this can be remedied by wrapping it in bash by doing `entry: bash -c 'cd packages/backend && mypy --config-file pyproject.toml .'`  but the same type issues mentioned above surface).

```
❯ mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml packages/backend/src
Success: no issues found in 92 source files
```

### Context

The above linked mypy-monorepo is just a slight directory structure change to this repo https://github.com/cofin/litestar-fullstack which has working pre-commits as it's a flat directory(it is the backend of the monorepo structure). I wanted to add a monorepo structure to it in order to have frontend and backend live alongside in the same repo (among other services).

I realized in order to do so I must move `.pre-commit-config.yaml` to the root of the monorepo, so far so good. However I then also realized I needed to edit the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` for all the hooks to recognize where the backend python `pyproject.toml` lived. I proceeded to do it for all the hooks in the my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. The `mypy` hook previously had the following

`entry: mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml` which worked great! I got 0 errors much like the aforementioned `mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml packages/backend/src` running from the root directory and I figured all was well.

I pushed this to Github and the github actions ran....and it failed because mypy was not recognized as an executable from the pre-commit `entry:`. I then realized that `entry` is not bash (I saw a previous issue where cd could not be done within entry for the same reason from pre-commit/issues/1110 and another issue) and that instead I would either have to pass the --config-file as an arg or wrap the entry with bash such as `entry: bash -c 'cd packages/backend && mypy --config-file pyproject.toml .'.

However no matter what I do I still get those 5 errors which don't seemingly happen when running `mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml` natively (whether in terminal on the root repo or using the mypy command within the pre-commit hook in entry). I tested editing the `pyproject.toml` to see if it was not being recognized and this is not the case, as if I change other `mypy` settings within my `pyproject.toml` more type errors pop up (which is a good thing as it shows I believe that pyproject.toml is being read correctly). I'm somewhat at a loss here and would really appreciate any assistance at all. I'm not sure if it's an issue of not reading "from" the directory or needing to have the venv of the directory itself. For example, is the env being read correctly?

**Steps to Reproduce:**
To very quickly get started with the `mypy-monorepo` and reproduce

```
mkdir mypy-monorepo
cd mypy-monorepo
git clone https://github.com/Faolain/mypy-monorepo.git .
cd packages/backend
make install
poetry shell
```

where make install as per https://github.com/cofin/litestar-fullstack#install-virtual-environment-and-node-packages simply does
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoTUf.png)

Note: I've tried cleaning my pre-commit cache between runs when available and the same 5 errors appear.

Note 2: slotscheck seems to work with bash but when trying the same bash wrapper with mypy I still get the same 5 type errors.

Note 3: Not sure if this is relevant but I went down a rabbit hole of `cd ~/.cache/pre-commit` grepping for mypy and then finding what I assumed was the latest folder and checking pip list/freeze and saw that aiosql and uvloop were not included, which are the same type issues cropping up on mypy. Unsure if related.

**pre-commit --version**
v3.3.3

**.pre-commit-config.yaml**

```
repos:
  # I couldn't include the rest because it's triggering the link spam filter on SO.
  # Check above for entire yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/ariebovenberg/slotscheck
    rev: v0.16.5
    hooks:
      - id: slotscheck
        exclude: "test_*|docs|migrations|scripts|packages/frontend"
        entry: bash -c 'cd packages/backend && env PYTHONPATH=src slotscheck'
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: "v1.4.1"
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        exclude: "packages/frontend"
        # entry: mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml
        args: ["--config-file", "packages/backend/pyproject.toml"]
        # args: [--config-file=./packages/backend/pyproject.toml]
        # entry: mypy --config-file packages/backend/pyproject.toml
        # entry: bash -c 'cd packages/backend && mypy --config-file pyproject.toml .'
        additional_dependencies:
          [
            pydantic,
            pydantic-settings,
            pylint-pydantic,
            jinja2,
            hiredis,
            passlib,
            rich,
            packaging,
            click,
            rich-click,
            polyfactory,
            structlog,
            aiosmtplib,
            alembic,
            asyncpg,
            asyncpg-stubs,
            httpx,
            pytest,
            pytest-docker,
            saq,
            https://github.com/litestar-org/litestar/archive/refs/heads/main.zip,
            types-freezegun,
            types-python-jose,
            types-click,
            types-redis,
            types-passlib,
            types-click,
            types-PyYAML,
            uvicorn,
          ]
```

Comment: *...saw that aiosql and uvloop were not included...* have you tried adding them to `additional_dependencies`?

Comment: Hey @STerliakov appreciate it! This is what I ended up doing in order to "fix it" but I don't understand why running the command as it was without it wasn't failing.